# why つぎの じゅぎょう is correct?when おもしろい じゅぎょう is without の?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Why つぎの じゅぎょう is correct when おもしろい じゅぎょう is without の? Can you explain, please? つぎ and おもしろい are both adjectives, are not they?

Comment: In fact つぎ is a noun and can be used standalone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different types of adjectives in Japanese and the way they modify something is different.

つぎ is what is sometimes known as a "no-adjective", which are words that are nouns in Japanese, but are used as adjectives in languages such as English. The typical way to make nouns into modifiers is by adding の so they really just follow this pattern. That's why we need the の in つぎ **の** じゅぎょう

おもしろい is what is known as a "i-adjective". They end in い, but not all things that end with い are "i-adjectives". They can attach directly to a noun to modify it, which is why おもしろい じゅぎょう is correct.

There are also "na-adjectives," which work by adding a な before the word they modify. For example, 好き{すき}**な**　じゅぎょう.